# Can't call webservice when upload it to server host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

Please to help me with problem about webservice:

**"Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type WebserviceLicenseKey.License_PaymentInfo."**

When i use localhost with webservice that is good. But when i update it to server host that can't get data and raise errors as above.

This is my code in webservice, i used dbml

```
**[WebMethod]
        [SoapDocumentMethod(Binding = "LicenseKeyService")]
        [SoapHeader("UserAccount", Required = true)]
        public List<License_PriceDayInfo> GetAllPriceDayInfo()
        {
            if (!CheckUserAccount())
                return null;
            return _context.License_PriceDayInfos.ToList();
        }**
```

and in the Client call webservice and get data as:

```
  **_userCredentials.UserName = "abc";
                _userCredentials.Password = "123456";
                _licenseWs.UserCredentialsValue = _userCredentials;
               var a = _licenseWs.GetAllPaymentInfo().ToList();**
```

Please to help me !!!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your data contracts you probably have a property of some type, that has a property back to its parent. The serializer cannot handle this by default as it would cause a never ending serialization.

To solve this, you can use flattened data contracts instead of hierarchical ones, so that you don't end up with these kind of relations (recommended), or use the [IsReference property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference(v=vs.110).aspx) on your data contract property. See example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i can't fix with that. you can see my webservice by the link http://licensews.thegioiphaidep.vn/licensews.asmx

Comment: Ah, i think i know how to fixed. Because webservice not transfer reference between tables.